# printk is not working sometimes in kernel driver

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I am facing some issue while printing a buffer (size is 4Mb) in `spi-pxa2xx.c` driver using `printk`.

In **`static int u8_writer(struct driver_data *drv_data)`** function, I have added a `printk` to print 4Mb data. Some of the data are not printed while spi transaction.

Is it actually good to use `printk` for this kind of debugging?

Comment: Hmm... Why on the Earth you need that?!

Comment: I have a flash chip(size is 4Mb) and it is connected to processor  via spi. I flashed the chip using Flashrom.  During write cycle , one byte is missing randomly(occurring 1 time if i flash 100 times) So i enabled a log in "u8_writer". I could capture the data during write cycle. But some times printk skips some bytes of data and starts to print data after that.

Comment: 4M (even Mbit) is way too much for `printk()` debugging method. Try something else.